# Firebase Admin SDK Cloud function not finding Firestore document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Background: I've been successfully using Firebase on the front-end using Auth, Firestore and Functions.

Situation: From a Cloud Function, I need to obtain information stored in Firestore via Admin SDK. I am not using any environment variable

Problem: I have not been able to read Firestore information from the Cloud function via Firebase Admin SDK. I find Admin SDK information a very scarse and lacking more details.

I am following these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd. But, noticed some instructions regarding Admin SDK service accounts(I suppose I have the default config) on this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

In Firestore I have the following structure. Collection called merchants with several documents. Each Document has several fields.

```
merchants 
    = > document1
        = > { email: email1, name: name1 }
```

The code I am currently attempting:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getFirestore, doc, getDoc} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

initializeApp();

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
 exports.helloWorld = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
   logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
   
   const getCollection = await getFirestore().collection("merchants").doc("document1").get()
   .then(doc =>{
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return response.send('Not Found')
      } 
        console.log(doc.data());
        return response.send(doc.data());
   }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });
 });
```

No error is displayed on the console other than the console.log Not Found msg.

Comment: Despite the fact you are mixing `async/await` and `then()` your function should work. Are you 100% sure the `document1` exists? Note also that `console.log()` will not work as you "you first need to require a special module to patch the standard methods", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?hl=en&authuser=0&gen=2nd#console-log. You can also remove the `const admin = require('firebase-admin');` line.

Comment: In addition, you should try updating both the Firebase CLI and the SDK as explained in the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?hl=en&authuser=0&gen=2nd#set-up-your-environment-and-the-firebase-cli

Comment: When you write "No error is displayed on the console other than the console.log Not Found msg." which "console" are you referring to??

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec for taking a look at the question. Yes, document1 does exist. In fact, I am able to read the document contents from the client side, but not via Cloud function Admin SDK. The console I am referring about is the CMD to launch the cloud function emulator firebase emulators:start

Comment: Did you try to deploy your Cloud Function?

Comment: Found it. Firestore emulator was being initilized, but I was not aware of that. I followed the tutorial which uses firestore emulator, but I only wanted cloud functions emulator. Added some data to the firestore emulator and it finds the collection doc.

Not sure whether this question should be deleted or left open as reference.

Comment: You may write an anwser